# Heroku Images gone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, heroku

After updating images for many products on HerokuApp, I came back some minutes later to see that all images of the products but two are missing?

Is this normal or is this fixable?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you store them at Heroku and how did you upload them ?

Comment: I'm using spree, and through the spree console I can tie an image to a product.

Comment: I am not too sure how Spree works. But basically only files in your asset pipeline are persistent. (Stored in app/asset/images then precompiled into public folder) what you should do is host those images at a cloud service (not sure if this is what you do through the spree console, this is why I asked)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't allow you to save images to it due to its ephemereal storage unless they're a part of your assets folder and precompiled.  For uploading images you need to tie it into AmazonS3 (or some other image store) because only the database data persists.  Here's a heroku dev guide that shows how to use AmazonS3 to store images and why they can't be saved on Heroku's platform itself:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku

Comment: The intent above is correct, but a small clarification. Heroku does allow the use of the file system but it is strongly discouraged. Since the filesystem is ephemeral and the dynos restart once per day, you will lose anything you've written to the fs on that restart. Small point but important distinction.